# Transparent profile pictures should be rendered on a dark background in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode, avatar

I've recently changed my profile picture to an image with a transparent background.  While this looks great on the light theme:

[image: top bar profile in light mode]
[image: usercard on post in light mode]

It doesn't look nearly as good on the dark theme, because it keeps the white background, which ends up looking out of place:

[image: top bar profile in dark mode]
[image: usercard on post in dark mode]

Compare this to the profile page in dark mode, where it renders with transparency and looks great:

[image: profile page profile image in dark mode]

Could it be fixed to be transparent so that it renders onto whatever color the background is?  Or if this is infeasible, at least a dark color?

Comment: I also see the white background in the light theme, when you are the OP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNPxQ.png

Comment: The white background is part of the image itself. It’s still a PNG, and it’s served from Imgur with the `?s=32` parameter (in the expanded user-card it’s `?s=128` with the same whie background. Only on the profile does it have `?s=328`, but it’s the full 1312px × 1312px image there. As all of this is done by Imgur, this may be out of Stack Exchange’s hands. You could try to make the transparency “black transparent”, i.e. `#00000000`, and then save the PNG with the option to store color information in transparent pixels. Maybe Imgur then turns the pixels to black, at least.

Comment: I did try using a `#00000000` background. The image is generated by a Python [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) script that sets up the image via `im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), '#00000000')`.  So I think it should be "black transparent," although if it's not, I may have made a mistake exporting it.

Comment: @RyanM Ah, true, I can confirm that the pixels are `#00000000` and not `#ffffff00`. So it’s Imgur’s fault. I don’t know if SE can fix this.